# How do you configure Apache 2.2 / 2.4 to apply back pressure

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mpm-worker

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get Apache to return a 503 (server busy) under heavy load. I'm using the worker MPM module. What I'm seeing is that when MaxClients is reached, Apache just hangs and will not response to any future requests, requiring a restart of httpd.

It doesn't seem to make a difference how I tune the MPM module settings. Whenever MaxClients is tripped, Apache seems to get hung.

Does anyone know how to configure the worker MPM module to apply back pressure?

Comment: What, specifically, have you tried?

Comment: I have tried tuning the process and thread limit config settings, and MaxClients, but I don't think I'm on the right track. I have not yet experimented with LimitBacklog,or modified any system socket settings. I'm using an Ubuntu server.

Comment: The next thing I'm gonna try is configure ServerLimit / ThreadsPerChild and MaxClients such that MaxClients is higher than ServerLimit * ThreadsPerChild, I'm also going to try setting LimitBackLog to a low number (It defaults to 511 I believe).

Comment: I should mention how I'm testing this. I have Apache in front of Tomcat, connected via mod_jk. I've built a dead simple rest API with a single route /delay that just does Thread.sleep, with interval supplied as a route parameter. I'm using JMeter to put load on Apache, using the /delay route.